# How to add a space between each number followed by a letter

Tags: regex, replace, emacs

I'm trying to use `emacs` 's `query-replace` feature to insert a space between each instance where I have a number folowe by a letter.

In this example, I have several citations. In each case I have an author, then year, then journal. For *reasons* there is a space missing between the year and the journal. However, I can't seem to figure out a good regular expression to add in the space.

> ```
> [1] Schnetzer A et al. 2017Harmful Algae
> [2] Sekula-Wood E et al. 2009Nat Geosci
> [3] Preece EP et al. 2017Harmful Algae
> [4] Tango PJ, Butler W 2008Northeast Nat
> [5] Backer LC et al. 2013Toxins
> [6] Dillenberg HO, Dehnel MK 1960Can Med Assoc J
> [7] Turner PC et al. 1990BMJ
> ```

Any guidance?

Comment: `[0-9]` matches a number, `[a-z]` matches a letter. Put them each in a capture group, and replace with `\1 \2`.

Answer (score 2):

Each line up to the furthest "four digits followed by a non-space" sequence can be matched with `^\(\[[0-9]+\] .* [0-9]\{4\}\)\([^ ]\)` and then `\1 \2` as a replacement will insert the missing space.

Be sure to actually use `query-replace-regexp`, though -- `query-replace` doesn't deal with regexps at all.